# Google Analytics does not show any referrers from link to my site I created in a forum

Tags: seo, google, analytics, backlinks

I added a link to my site on a forum.  In source code I not see `nofollow` so this is `follow` link which need be detect in Google Analytics - acquisitions - referral.

I clicked on this link which I added on forum, but I am not seeing it appear in  Google Analytics?  Why? Is this a good or bad back link?

Comment: Make sure that Forum link is including redirection to your website. If you can, please share the forum link to let me have a look for better understanding. Also, you will need to wait for a day in order to view correct data in Analytics.

Comment: e.g. this forum https://www.democraticunderground.com/10141757698 you see link in post http://www.businessinsider.com/hawaii-fires-back-at-jeff-sessions-2017-4 so traffic from this link in google analytics show like ''direct'' and need be ''referral''

Comment: This is because you are redirecting your own domain from http://www.businessinsider.com/hawaii-fires-back-at-jeff-sessions-2017-4 to http://www.businessinsider.in/hawaii-fires-back-at-jeff-sessions-after-he-called-the-state-an-island-in-the-pacific-ocean/articleshow/58290161.cms  You will need to stop this redirection in order to get the data as "referral" instead of "direct".

Comment: I can see that you are using redirecting to country level domain. So I think Cross Domain Analytics will help you with this: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en

Comment: I paste this link like example, my domain not redirect and I not have more country extensions I have just one .com

Comment: I'm from India so the domain is redirecting to .in from .com
I think Cross Domain Anlaytics setup can help you with this.

Comment: as I see I paste businessinsider.com like example, my domain not redirect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57528/discussion-between-shivbhadrasinh-gohil-and-nikola99).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not you get referrals recorded in Google Analytics acquisitions - referral report is irrelevant for whether or not the link counts for SEO.

Google Analytics measures when people click on the link.   The referrer that their browser sends is what ends up in that report.    A `nofollow` on the link will not prevent Google Analytics from doing its reporting.   A `rel=noreferrer` on the link would prevent the referrer from being sent.

To count a link for SEO, Googlebot must crawl it.  Googlebot would have to download the forum page.   The page would have to allow crawling.   At that point a nofollow on a link would cause Googlebot to ignore the link.

If you want to see if Google has found the link for SEO, look in the links report of Google Search Console.   Keep in mind that it takes several weeks for Google to do the crawling, and even then Google doesn't report on every link it finds.   Just because it doesn't appear in the report, it doesn't mean that Google didn't count the link.

I would also discourage you from posting links in forums for the purpose of improving your back link profile.   That is spammy.   If Google find out you are doing so (for example from this post), they may choose to penalize your site.